# Kivy Camera rotated 90 degrees

Tags: python, android, kivy, android-camera, kivymd

I've used Camera from kivy library and on Windows it appears correctly, but when I try it on the Android platform it seems to be rotated for 90 degrees.

I have tried method with canvas rotation Push and PopMatrix

```
Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: -90
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
```

from [Kivy Camera display is rotated -90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979741/kivy-camera-display-is-rotated-90-degrees) but it didn't help. I use python declarative style for my code

```
self.camera = Camera(
            play=True,

        )

        bottom_box = AnchorLayout(
            size_hint=(1, 0.1)
        )

        take_pic_button = MDIconButton(
            icon='circle',
            theme_icon_color="Custom",
            icon_color=(255 / 255, 255 / 255, 255 / 255, 1),
            icon_size='50sp',
            size_hint=(None, None),
            pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
            ripple_scale=0,
        )

        take_pic_button.bind(
            on_release=self.take_picture
        )
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using XCamera.Easier to use it. It provides more simple implementations.
https://github.com/kivy-garden/xcamera